# Signalr "No Connection with that ID" error from ASP.NET application on IIS

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis, signalr

I have an ASP.NET & Angular application running on IIS on Windows Server 2019. After I moved the application to another server, I started receiving "**No Connection with that ID**" errors, so some critical functionality of the application is not working.

Interestingly, it happens after some time. When I log in, it works well in the beginning. After a few minutes, I start seeing **404 errors** in the console. And, when I try going that link(https://mywebsite.com/api/Hubs/ReservationHub?id=xxx) directly on my browser, I get "No Connection with that ID".

I don't see any error logs in the server. Cloudflare is used for DNS.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure no error logs in server? Please check IIS log more careful. If there's no error logs, that means IIS never receive this request. You didnot send request correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like session persistence is not enabled or not working correctly. It is also called session affinity | "sticky" sessions.

This is to ensure that requests for the same user always go to the same server. SignalR requires that all requests for a single connection go to the same physical server. If any request ends up getting routed to a different server, you'll get a 404 "No Connection with that ID".

You can get the network trace of failed connections to get a better overview, but this is the cause most of the times.

Comment: Did you find what was wrong? @mustafa

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to enable WebSockets in IIS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-6.0

The URL you see in console should be wss://mywebsite.com/api/Hubs/ReservationHub?id=xxx

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error, but everything was on the same machine/server.

The reason was `hostingModel="outofprocess"` (web.config). After changing `inprocess` the problem went away.